# HttpClient Returns 404 not found

Tags: xamarin, httpclient

I have a xamarin app that pull data from a webAPI. I check api address so many times and i am sure it is correct. When i debug my code i have 404 not found error from server. However when i copy and paste the URL to browser i have expected result. I couldn't figure out why my app return 404.

My Method:

```
   public async Task<ICustomerType> GetById(int id)
    {
        string _token;

        if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("token"))
        {
            _token = (string)App.Current.Properties["token"];
        }
        else
        { _token = null; }

        var webApiResponse =
            _connector.PostAsync(
                "api/Customer/get/id/" + id,
                string.Empty, _token).Result;

        var response = webApiResponse.Result.ToString();

        var jObjectResponse = JObject.Parse(response);

        ICustomerType customerTypeObj = null;

        return customerTypeObj;
    }
```

My bridge method to HttpClient's PostAsync method:

```
    private async Task<TResponse> PostAsync(string requestPath, string 
jsonContent, bool getToken, string token)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

            if (getToken)
            {
                token =  GetApiTokenAsync().Result;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            }

            var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync(requestPath, httpContent).Result;
            var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(jsonData);

    }
```

Token: Correct

API Url: Correct(I check "/" signs from debug output.They are well placed. My Api like: 
 https://MyApi.net/api/Personel/get/id/1)

My Error:

> - response    {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Request-Context:
>     appId=cid-v1:Some_String   Server: Kestrel
>     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=Some_Int   Set-Cookie:
>     ARRAffinity=Some_String;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=MyDomain   Date: Mon,
>     09 Jul 2018 07:54:19 GMT   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   Content-Length: 0
>     }}    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method verb in API is "GET" but you used "POST" in the client So in browser works because browser call "GET", but in the client doesn't work.

instead of :

```
   var webApiResponse =
        _connector.PostAsync(
            "api/Customer/get/id/" + id,
            string.Empty, _token).Result;
```

use :

```
   var webApiResponse =
        _connector.GetAsync(
            "api/Customer/get/id/" + id,
            string.Empty, _token).Result;
```